# How to text wrap to next line in Vuetify when class text-wrap not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, class, vuetify.js, word-wrap

I have cards that cut off words, moving them to a new line:
[image]

I tried to use `class="text-wrap"`, but it doesn't work:

```
  <div>
    <v-card max-width="1000" elevation="6">
      <div class="mb-8 text-wrap">
        <v-sheet dark color="grey darken-2" class="text-wrap">
          <v-card-title
            color="grey darken-2 white--text"
            class="d-block font-weight-regular text-wrap">
            {{ label }}
          </v-card-title>
        </v-sheet>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try adding an inline style as `word-break: break-word;` to the `v-card-title`

Comment: Style as in CSS!? What I am saying is `<v-card-title style="word-break: break-word;" ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @Chin.Udara solution is:
`<v-card-title style="word-break: break-word"...`